# How to change URL Websocket NodeJs (server/client)

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, websocket

I have a server node Js with express I want to use two socket with my clients in the same page server.js (contains all my controllers), suddenly I want to put the first socket under the url ("/connection"), and A second one under the url ("/giveUserConnected") that will serve me to recupir the connected users, par exemple :

```
client.html :
var socket = io.connect('http://127.0.0.1:9999/connection');
```

To contact `server.js :`

```
app.get('/connection',function (req,res) {
    io.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log('a user connected'); 
    });
});
```

and another socket2 in `client.html :`

```
var socket2 = io.connect('http://127.0.0.1:9999/giveUserConnected');
```

to contact `server.js :`

```
app.get('/giveUserConnected',function (req,res) {
    io.on('connection', function(socket){
      // to recuper list of users connected 
    });
});
```

but it does not work 
what is the solution , thank's

Comment: The answer is the documentation of socket.io. Check for something called NAMESPACE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing HTTP requests with `socket.io` requests, which are two different things.

When you provide a path name to `io.connect()` (in this case, `/connection` and `/giveUserConnected`), the `socket.io` server uses the path as the name to a [namespace](https://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/#custom-namespaces) that the client connects to.

What I think you want is to just create an event handler for a particular message that will return the list of users. You could use [acknowledgement functions](https://socket.io/docs/#sending-and-getting-data-(acknowledgements)) for that:

```
// server
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
  socket.on('giveUserConnected', function(fn) {
    fn(listOfUsers);
  });
});

// client
socket.emit('giveUserConnected', function(users) {
  ...
});
```

What `listOfUsers` is depends on your app.

Comment: ah thank's you man, very good solution, 
I did not think about it